# Can "distort" be used as a reflexive verb?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Can "distort" be used as a reflexive verb?

for example, can I say:
"However, due to the high interphasial length of the substrate, the shape of the phase separation has distorted"

or must I say:
"However, due to the high interphasial length of the substrate, the shape of the phase separation has become distorted"

or:
"However, due to the high interphasial length of the substrate, the shape of the phase separation has been distorted"

Comment: The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has+distorted%2C+has+been+distorted%2C+has+become+distorted&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chas%20distorted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chas%20been%20distorted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chas%20become%20distorted%3B%2Cc0) shows equal usage of 'has been distorted' in comparisonto 'has distorted' with a very small smattering at the bottom of 'has become distorted'. Interesting. (No significant difference AmE/BrE.)

Comment: _Has been distorted_ sounds more natural.

Comment: Please look up *distort* in a good dictionary. You will see that *shape* is not needed.  "... due to the high interphasial length of the substrate,  phase separation has distorted" -- better still, use the adjective in place of the verb -- " ... phase separation **is distorted**."

Comment: **1.1** [no object] Become twisted out of shape. ‘the pipe will distort as you bend it’; ‘The shadows warped and distorted as a humanoid shape detached itself.’ https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/distort

Answer (score 1):

Those three uses aren't examples of the verb distort being used reflexively.

The first case:

> the shape of the phase separation has distorted.

Is a case of using distort intransitively (not taking an object) in a present perfect tense. example: "The situation has changed."

The second case:

> the shape of the phase separation has become distorted

Is an example of using the past participle of distort as an adjective. It's preceded by the present perfect tense of "to become". An example, "The committee is corrupt/ed", "The committee is corrupted", "The committee has been corrupted", "the committee has become corrupted". There are many many past participles you can use as adjectives.

The third example:

> the shape of the phase separation has been distorted

This is "to be distorted" in the present perfect tense. It is also in the passive voice because something has been done to it without mention of who or what did it. Example: Active voice "God creates all men", Passive voice: "All men are created."

The actual meaning of reflexive verb is:

> a verb whose direct object is the same as its subject, for example, "I
>   wash myself".
>
> Source: Wikipedia.

Reflexive use would be "has distorted itself" or something along those lines.

Anyone please correct me if I've made mistakes, I'm not a teacher.

Having said all that, I think all three are fine, but the first is less preferable. Out of the second two. Use "separation has become distorted" if all you want convey is that it has become distorted, and use "separation has been distorted" if you want to emphasise an agent/something which caused it to be distorted.

For example "John has become scared" vs "John has been scared", the second one has more of a connotation that something or someone has scared John. Hope that makes sense.